# Same docker compose works for all my team but not for me

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-m1, apple-silicon

## Initial Situation

My entire team has the same laptop. The 16' Apple m1 pro 64 GB. This is relevant, because docker and m1 don't get along so well.

The team uses the same docker compose. It will be the last thing at the bottom of the post, since it is quite long.

Point is, I used to get this error:

```
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

### Installation process

```
$ brew install --cask docker
$ softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

I then went to:

1. settings -> general -> use virtualization framework
2. settings -> Features in development -> Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation

Then:

```
$ docker compose up -d
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

### Troubleshooting

I commented out everything and tried images one by one. Debizium was the culprit.

```
debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:2.2
    container_name: debezium-myapp
    # platform: linux/amd64
    ...
```

I left it commented to explain that by default, that line is not there. After scouring the internet, I found the solution to specify the platform. Then I added the (uncommented) version of that line.

And now, everything works.

---

## Questions

1. Adding the platform ... what does it actually do? Does it tell docker what env to emulate?
2. Why is it only me that has the issue? What configuration could I have on my end that would fix this without adding said line?
3. Will adding said line impact other people using the `docker-compose`? Intel macs? Windows pcs? Linux users?

---

## The full docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  postgres:
    image: debezium/postgres:14-alpine
    container_name: postgres-my-app
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pg_volume_my_app:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeper-myapp
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeper:2888:3888
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka-myapp
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:7.3.2
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    depends_on: [ zookeeper ]
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9999
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: 172.17.0.1
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9999:9999"
    expose:
      - "19092"
  
  debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:2.2
    container_name: debezium-myapp
    # platform: linux/amd64
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:19092
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_offsets
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
    depends_on: [ kafka ]
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    volumes:
      - debezium_volume_myapp:/var/lib/debezium/data

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.2
    container_name: schema-registry-myapp
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:19092
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081,http://localhost:8081
    ports:
      - 9191:8081
    depends_on: [ kafka ]

volumes:
  pg_volume_my_app:
    driver: local
  debezium_volume_myapp:
    driver: local
networks:
  my-app-network:
    name: my-app-network
```

Comment: did you try with x86_64? like   platform:linux/x86_64

Comment: Has nothing to do with the question, I won't even try.